# how to manage myself SIGINT and SIGTERM signals?

Tags: perl, signals, mojolicious, mojolicious-lite

I am working on a simple `Mojolicious::Lite` based server that includes a websocket end point.

I would like to handle some termination signals to terminate gracefully the websocket connections and avoid exceptions in the clients (a java application).

I have tried to define my signal handlers like I am used to with my previous servers using `HTTP::Daemon`.
The problem is that they seem to be ignored. Perhaps redefined in the Mojolicious layer, I did not found any reference on it yet.

I am expecting to see my termination message, but it does not happen

```
[Mon Mar 23 14:01:28 2020] [info] Listening at "http://*:3000"
Server available at http://127.0.0.1:3000
^C  # <-- i want to see my signal received message here if type Ctrl-c
```

I am sending `SIGINT` directly by entering `Ctrl-C` when the server is in foreground in the terminal, and I can terminate gracefully the server (e.g. when started by a cron or other displayless mean) with a `kill <pid>`.

In some previous servers I tried to be quite exaustive by handling:

- `HUP` hijacked signal used nowadays to reload config
- `SIGINT` Ctrl-C
- `SIGQUIT` Ctrl-\
- `SIGABRT` e.g abnormal library termination
- `SIGTERM` external termination request - "friendly" `kill` (by opposition of brutal `kill -9`
- `TSTP` suspend with Ctrl-Z
- `CONT` when resuming from Ctrl-Z with `fg` or `bg`

All these handlers allow to exit gracefully with cleaning resources, ensuring data consistency or reload configuration or data models after external change, depending on the program and the needs.

I have found the package `Mojo::IOLoop::Signal`, « a Non-blocking signal handler » but it seems to be a different thing. Wrong?

Here is my simplified code (runs with a simple `perl ws_store_test.pl daemon`):

**File ws_store_test.pl**

```
# Automatically enables "strict", "warnings", "utf8" and Perl 5.10 features
use Mojolicious::Lite;

my $store = {};
my $ws_clients = {};

sub terminate_clients {
    for my $peer (keys %$ws_clients){
        $ws_clients->{$peer}->finish;
    }
}

$SIG{INT} = sub {
    say "SIGINT";  # to be sure to display something
    app->log->info("SIGINT / CTRL-C received. Leaving...");
    terminate_clients;
};
$SIG{TERM} = sub {
    say "SIGTERM"; # to be sure to display something
    app->log->info("SIGTERM - External termination request. Leaving...");
    terminate_clients;
};

# this simulates a change on datamodel and notifies the clients
sub update_store {
    my $t = localtime time;
    $store->{last_time} = $t;
    for my $peer (keys %$ws_clients){
        app->log->debug(sprintf 'notify %s', $peer);
        $ws_clients->{$peer}->send({ json => $store
                                       });
    }
}

# Route with placeholder - to test datamodel contents
get '/:foo' => sub {
  my $c   = shift;
  my $foo = $c->param('foo');
  $store->{$foo}++;
  $c->render(text => "Hello from $foo." . (scalar keys %$store ? " already received " . join ', ', sort keys %$store : "") );
};

# websocket service with optional parameter
websocket '/ws/tickets/*id' => { id => undef } => sub {
    my $ws = shift;
    my $id = $ws->param('id');

    my $peer = sprintf '%s', $ws->tx;
    app->log->debug(sprintf 'Client connected: %s, id=%s', $peer, $id);
    $ws_clients->{$peer} = $ws->tx;
    $store->{$id} = {};

    $ws->on( message => sub {
        my ($c, $message) = @_;
        app->log->debug(sprintf 'WS received %s from a client', $message);
             });

    $ws->on( finish => sub {
        my ($c, $code, $reason) = @_;
        app->log->debug(sprintf 'WS client disconnected: %s - %d - %s', $peer, $code, $reason);
        delete $ws_clients->{$peer};
             });
};

plugin Cron => ( '* * * * *' => \&update_store );

# Start the Mojolicious command system
app->start;
```

Comment: How do you send the SIGINT to the daemon?

Comment: @HåkonHægland for `SIGINT` by using `Ctrl-C` while the server is in foreground, for `SIGTERM` it can be via `kill <pid>`. I will update my question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

SIGINT and SIGTERM handlers are redefined at the start of the server. In [morbo](https://github.com/mojolicious/mojo/blob/160fb89db1075d3f57e6496f2480f85be26e9373/lib/Mojo/Server/Morbo.pm#L24-L27) this is:

```
local $SIG{INT} = local $SIG{TERM} = sub {
  $self->{finished} = 1;
  kill 'TERM', $self->{worker} if $self->{worker};
};
```

In [Mojo::Server::Daemon](https://github.com/mojolicious/mojo/blob/b3232bb96ccf24c7b53251af4c1fe6d8a40214b6/lib/Mojo/Server/Daemon.pm#L36) this is:

```
local $SIG{INT} = local $SIG{TERM} = sub { $loop->stop };
```

If you redefine SIGINT/SIGTERM's handler yourself at the toplevel, those `local` will override them. What I suggest instead, is to redefine them once in a [`before_dispatch`](https://mojolicious.org/perldoc/Mojolicious#before_dispatch) hook. For instance:

```
sub add_sigint_handler {
    my $old_int = $SIG{INT};
    $SIG{INT} = sub {
        say "SIGINT";  # to be sure to display something
        app->log->info("SIGINT / CTRL-C received. Leaving...");
        terminate_clients;
        $old_int->(); # Calling the old handler to cleanly exit the server
    }
}

app->hook(before_dispatch => sub {
    state $unused = add_sigint_handler();
});
```

Here I'm using [`state`](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/state.html) to make sure that `add_sigint_handler` is evaluated only once (since if it was evaluated more than once, `$old_int` would not have the correct value after the first time). Another way of writing that could be:

```
my $flag = 0;
app->hook(before_dispatch => sub {
    if ($flag == 0) {
        add_sigint_handler();
        $flag = 1;
    }
});
```

Or,

```
app->hook(before_dispatch => sub {
    state $flag = 0;
    if ($flag == 0) {
        add_sigint_handler();
        $flag = 1;
    }
});
```